# pytest: how to temporarly close internet connection?

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I am currently building a program that scraps data on some websites on a regular basis with the `requests` module. This program needs to be robust over some internet connection failures (ie my full python module catches the `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` exception and returns an empty DataFrame).
I would like to test my module (pytest) when the internet is up (ie I successfully managed to gather data), but also in the case internet is down (ie the return values are empty data frame).

My question is: Is there a way to simulate an internet failure into some `pytest` tests ?

I've reproduced the pytests I need into the 2 files below. The function `test_ping_yahoo` returns `True` if the ping succeeds, `False` otherwise (either internet is down, or the status_code is not equal to 200).

Then, I would like to configure 2 tests: one with the internet up, the other one with the internet down. I've been searching a while without success.

Bonus: the solution does not involve superuser access ;)

File `test_ping.py`:

```py
# !/usr/bin/python3

import pytest
import ping

def test_ping_yahoo():
    result = ping.ping_website("https://www.yahoo.com/")
    assert result == True

def test_ping_yahoo_closing_internet_connection():
    ## Is there a command to temporary close internet connexion ??
    close_internet_connection():
    result = ping.ping_website("https://www.yahoo.com/")
    assert result == False
```

File `ping.py`:

```py
# !/usr/bin/python3

import requests

def ping_website(url):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url, timeout=1.)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return False
```

Comment: E.g. with `requests-mock`: https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#raising-exceptions

Comment: @hoefling: thanks, I was not aware about this module. I managed to test my module.